# Damage function for a game

Tags: php, battle-simulation

For my game I have a function that resolves `FireOrders` between units. The function is being called a ton of times and it's only being extended from various classes.

I have this: `doDamage()` for a `Particle`-Parent, a `Matter`-Parent and so on (5 in total).

The functions are the same, except for a very little `if`/`else` part that splits up a number into two different numbers.

It is very annoying to me to have this "long" function in every weapon class and I would like to somehow outsource the actual damage-determination part, because basicly this is what's different for the weapon classes and the remaining function is entirely the same.

However, I'm unable to come up with a way to outsource this tiny element. I tried to write two functions (`getArmourDamage()` and `getStructDamage()`), but it is not working since both values depend on each other, hence a single function return value won't suffice.

```
function doDamage($fire){
 // this is being called in context Particle::doDamage, Matter::doDamage, Explosive::doDamage etc

    for ($i = 0; $i < $fire->shots; $i++){
        if ($fire->rolls[$i] <= $fire->req){
            $destroyed = false;
            $shielDmg = 0;
            $armourDmg = 0;
            $structDmg = 0;
            $totalDmg = $this->getDamage($fire) * $this->getDamageMod(); // INT

            $armour = $fire->target->getStructureById($fire->hitSection);
            $hitSystem = $fire->target->getHitSystem($fire);
            $remInt = $hitSystem->getRemainingIntegrity();
            $negation = $armour->getRemainingNegation($fire) * $hitSystem->getArmourMod(); // INT


             // VARIABLE PART
                if ($totalDmg <= $negation/2){
                    $armourDmg = ceil($totalDmg/2);
                }
                else {
                    $armourDmg = ceil(min($totalDmg, $negation));
                    $structDmg = ceil($totalDmg - $armourDmg);
                }
             // ENDS HERE


            if ($remInt - $structDmg < 1){
                $destroyed = true;
                $hitSystem->destroyed = true;
                Debug::log("overkill for: ".($structDmg - $remInt));
            }

            $dmg = new Damage(
                -1,
                $fire->id,
                $fire->gameid,
                $fire->targetid,
                $armour->id,
                $hitSystem->id,
                $fire->turn,
                $fire->rolls[$i],
                $fire->weapon->type,
                $totalDmg,
                $shielDmg,
                $structDmg,
                $armourDmg,
                0,
                $negation,
                $destroyed,
                "",
                1
            );
            $fire->damages[] = $dmg;
            $hitSystem->damages[] = $dmg;
            $armour->damages[] = $dmg;
            Debug::log("armour rem: ".$armour->getRemainingIntegrity()." / ".$armour->integrity.", now adding: ".$armourDmg);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For reference, these are the various differences per class:

```
   particle
                if ($totalDmg <= $negation/2){
                    $armourDmg = ceil($totalDmg/2);
                }
                else {
                    $armourDmg = ceil(min($totalDmg, $negation));
                    $structDmg = ceil($totalDmg - $armourDmg);
                }

   matter
                $armourDmg = $negation / 2;
                $structDmg = $totalDmg - $armourDmg;

   ballistic
                $armourDmg = min($totalDmg, $negation *2);
                $structDmg = $totalDmg - $armourDmg;
```

Comment: I would imagine that you would get a much more useful review if you included full code for the classes involved. My guess is that you have problems with your overall inheritance design and starting your review with the higher-level class interfaces might be a better way to start to address your concern.

Comment: @Jamal how can i make the topic be more specific than state what my question really is ? I want to move the specidies part out of the function, but since i need two variables, a single function, i.e. calculateDamage($totalDmg, $negation) wont do.

Comment: By stating the actual purpose of the code, not the request.

Comment: I guess the first problem you want to tackle is not the function shown above, but the constructor and the dependencies for the `new Damage()` class. There are ~100 arguments just to instantiate.

Comment: @kaiser The Damage class is just an object that is constructed and then inserted into the DB (every prop = 1 column). Is has no methods whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Please see comment above about thinking about broader review. My guess is that you might have a flawed approach to how you are modelling real-world items in your application. For example, a particle/matter/explosive doesn't really "doDamage" right? It "attacks" or "fires" or whatever you might want to call it.

"Damage" as a concept results from what the properties of the attack and the properties of the thing attacked are right?   So why would you model "damage" as a method on the different attacker entities, when it truly is something that needs to be determined based on the properties of both the attack and the target. Putting the actual calculation in the attacker class would not seem to make sense when you think about it.

You might look through [another review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144040/simple-factory-pattern-for-cooking-a-pizza/144136#144136) I gave where the poster was having a similar problem in modelling application entities to match real world behavior. I hope this may give some insight into how you should be thinking about writing your code.

---

That being said, if you aren't looking to potentially refactor your application, your problem should actually be easy to solve.  Just break that "variable" area of code out into it's own function:

So base class might look like:

```
function doDamage($fire) {
    // all your code common to every class in hierarchy


    // call method (overridden with specific logic in each inheriting class
    // possibly this method returns your Damage object
    $dmg = $this->calculateDamage($someParam, $someOtherParam, ...);

    // other code common to all classes in hierarchy
}
```

And you only override such code in inheriting classes if logic totally varies from that execution path.

---

Why does this method always return `true`? Is it really even meaningful to have a return from a method is the value is always the same?

Comment: Hello. Firstly there is some sense in my code. It might be not be apparent tho.
Class structure: System (Structure, Bridge, Weapon). Weapons here extend into types (Laser, Particle, Matter). So if have a System that holds a specific type of damage.
Now, in regards to your suggestion, consider this: In order to calculate damage, i need $totalDmg and $negation (armour) and i always return $armourDmg and $structDmg. I cant use a single function to get those values (unless i want to return an array).

Comment: I would highly advice **against** an _array_ of arguments for any function or method. This is unpredictable.

Comment: Yes, thats why im looking for another solution. At least i was right in that regard...

Comment: @user431806 my intent wasn't to pass an array literal, there. I guess I should not have you brackets there. I just meant that to be a placeholder for whatever arguments you need to pass.

Comment: No, thats not what i mean. As you see i calculate $armourDmg and $structDmg inside the doDamage() function, based on $totalDmg and $negation. What you suggest is a single function that can only return a single value, albeit i need two. The only way i know of to do that would require me to RETURN an array and then split it up post-return and that is whacky. Do you know what i mean ?

Comment: @user431806 I guess your question actually really demonstrates my primary point.  What business does a class that defines the properties of the attack have in determining how that attack impacts the given target? The design seems wrong to begin with.

Comment: Ok, im going to bite.
I have a SHIP class, which is made up from STUCTURE classes. STRUCTURES hold SYSTEMS. SYSTEMS are either of type WEAPON or of type PRIMARY (think bridge, reactor).
WEAPON is a baseclass and extends into LASER(weapon), MATTER(weapon) which holds the various methods needed for that class. 
Doing damage is done by creating a FIREORDER class and calling $SHIP->resolve($fireOrder). So the ship (target) itself receives the fireOrder and determines the damage done to itself.

I have no idea why would you think that makes no sense, or how to "better" it.

Comment: @user431806 Your post indicates that this method is in the weapons classes - `"It is very annoying to me to have this "long" function in every weapon class"`.  Perhaps that is a misstatement that is causing my concern?  Again, part of the reason why I first suggested that you might want to have a broader code review is that it is not really clear how your classes are interacting.  I think that the pattern of having a ship receive an object generated by a weapon firing against the ship, and having that ship resolve how such an object from the weapon impacts that ship is the right approach.

Comment: @user431806 But  if you are having the target ship resolve its own damage (which I noted in previous comment is likely a good approach), why would the resolution of the damages take place on a weapons class at all?  What if the target ship does not have the same kind of weapon as the ship that is firing on it?  What if the target ship has no weapons at all?  Why are weapons classes involved in resolving damage?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answer that your approach is somewhat flawed. I think that a deeper redesign is needed to really clean up the code. That being said, I have some comments I can make about what you have presented here.

As you already realize, the `doDamage` method is too long. There's lots of side effects inside the method. Things are happening that are unrelated to the name of the method, like the `Damage` object being constructed and passed into the database.  It would be much cleaner if each separate thing happening inside the method were split into its own method.

You say that you cannot separate the damage calculating code into its own method because you would have to return multiple things.  However, there's an easy answer to this. You can return an object!

I haven't written any php, but I think that you could have a method like this:

```
function GetDamageObject(arguments such as armor, damage, whatever)

    $damageObject = new DamageObject()
    if ($totalDmg <= $negation/2) {
        $armourDmg = ceil($totalDmg/2);
        $damageObject->armorDmg = $armourDmg;
    } else {
        $armourDmg = ceil(min($totalDmg, $negation));
        $structDmg = ceil($totalDmg - $armourDmg);
        $damageObject->armourDmg = $armourDmg;
        $damageObject->structDmg = $structDmg;
    }

    return $damageObject;
}
```

That code by itself will not work, but I think it conveys the idea well enough. Instead of having a method with lots of side effects, change the structure of your code so that you can return objects when you need to return multiple arguments. Then the top level code could look more like this:

```
function doDamage($fire) {

    $damageObject = GetDamageObject($fire, etc) //calculate damage done
    applyDamage(damageObject, target) //apply damage to target
    //if the damage needs to be seen by other systems,  you can do that here
    saveDamage(damageObject) //save whatever information needed to the database

}
```

Comment: I havent thought about returning an object or associative array. I agree its a good idea.  I will think about your general suggestions. Thanks for the effort.